# Registering an application in Azure AD to access office 365 application

Tags: azure, office365

I am trying to develop an application which uses the office 365 APIs . 
I have created an Azure Directory and created an native client application. 
When configuring my application there was an option to give permissions to other applications i need to use office 365 exchange application . 
When I try to add that application to azure AD it says it costs 300 $.

Is there a way to use it as a trial one ???

I am not getting the office 365 exchange online option . What should i do?
[image: My Azure Directory]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not expected. It sounds like maybe it was trying to add the service to your subscription, rather than permissions. Can you provide a screenshot?

You may want to try this guide for registering:
https://github.com/jasonjoh/office365-azure-guides/blob/master/RegisterAnAppInAzure.md

Comment: I have attached the screenshot for my azure directory. please let me know why am i not getting the office 365 option over here?

Comment: Ok, I'm just guessing here, but it looks like you only signed up for an Azure trial? You actually need an Office 365 subscription (which includes Azure). https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/HowTo/setup-development-environment